# create procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

please hep, I am trying to create a procedure that will  display 4 parameters whenever I enter a parameter. This is my code below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_emp_info
(       @EmployeeID         INT,
        @EmployeeID         INT             OUTPUT,
        @LastName           VARCHAR(30)     OUTPUT,
        @FirstName          VARCHAR(15)     OUTPUT,
        @Phone              VARCHAR(10)     OUTPUT      )
AS
SELECT @EmployeeID,
      @LastName,
     @FirstName,
     @Phone
FROM    Employees
WHERE   EmployeeID = @EmployeeID    
GO
```

This is bringing this error

> The variable name '@EmployeeID' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@LastName"

I have EmployeeID as both input and output. When I tried to remove the output  by running the below :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_emp_info
(       @EmployeeID         int,
        @LastName           VARCHAR(30)     OUTPUT,
        @FirstName          VARCHAR(15)     OUTPUT,
        @Phone              VARCHAR(10)     OUTPUT      )
AS
SELECT @EmployeeID,
    @LastName,
    @FirstName,
    @Phone
FROM    Employees
WHERE   EmployeeID = @EmployeeID    
GO
```

that worked, but the  procedure wont run . eg I ran

```
EXECUTE sp_emp_info 7
```

It brough this error:

> Procedure or function 'sp_emp_info' expects parameter '@LastName', which was not supplied.

What do you think I am doing wrong? Thank you .

Comment: Your question is tagged mysql but the code looks an awful like SQL Server.

Comment: In MySQL you call stored procedures with `CALL sp_emp_info(7)`

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, its SQL server

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a default value for the optional parameters. In this case I set them to `NULL`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_emp_info
    (       @EmployeeID         int      )
    AS
    SELECT EmployeeID
        LastName,
        FirstName,
        Phone
    FROM    Employees
    WHERE   EmployeeID = @EmployeeID    
    GO
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. When I did what you suggested it didn't return any data in the execute statement

Comment: I modified the answer. You were using variables to hold the information. I don't know if this was necessary or not because we don't know what you have to do with the data. This edited code just return a dataset.  I just want to show you that the code works and gets rid of the error you were receiving. @user7269554

Comment: DIdn't return any data? Do you mean it returned a table with some columns but no rows?

Comment: It returned tables with NULL values where there should be figures.  I have figured it out now. I posted the asnwer. Thank you ever so Nick.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was going about this the complex way. this simple coding:

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_emp_info
(       @EmployeeID         int     )
AS
SELECT  EmployeeID,
        LastName,
        FirstName,
        Phone
FROM    Employees
WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
GO

solved my problem. 
Thank you everyone.Much appreciated

Comment: This was @SQLChao solution except that he accounted for the fact that you wanted a bunch of redundant parameters. It would be polite if you acknowledged this

Comment: @SQLChao my apologies, I did'nt see your modified answer and comment. Yes your code works. Thank you so much. You guys are awesome